# Android keyTextColor Issue with Color

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having some trouble with keyTextColor inside Android Studio:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html#attr_android:keyTextColor

For some reason, "#00255" doesn't follow the "#rgb" format.  Why is that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there needs to be 6 numbers, not 5. Or you can use 3. Try #002255 and see what that does

Answer (score 0):

The RGB range values between 0 and 255. Example:

```
int integerColor = Color.rgb(255, 255, 255); // color white (0, 0, 0) is black
myTextView.setTextColor(color);
```

The values of the hexadecimal range 0 to F Example:

```
String hexColor = "#FFFFFF"; // color white #000000 is black
myTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(hexColor));
```

Do not confuse rgb colors with hexadecimal colors are totally different things!